# TypeError- Cannot convert undefined or null to object. Trying to convert state object values to json array string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While trying to fit the input form data to a JSON array string, I am getting an error

> Cannot convert undefined or null to object.

Below is the code which I tried to use on the state data:

```
const test = this.state.values;
Object.keys(test).forEach(key=>test[key]=[test[key]]);
```

When I do `console.log(test)` the data is as below:

```
Object
input1: {i: "ytuy"}
input2: {x: "tyutyu"}
```

My final goal is to have the JSON output as:

```
{
   "input1":[{"i":"ytuy"}],
   "input2":[{"x":"tyutyu"}]
}
```

Can anyone suggest why I get this error?

Comment: You shouldn't directly mutate the `state` object.

Comment: could you please help me on how i can perform Object.keys(test).forEach(key=>test[key]=[test[key]]);  on state data

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you are trying to do is to to each property value into a single-entry array.  You can do that by mapping your object with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

As mentioned in the comments, it is critical that you do not mutate the current object since this will mutate your component's state.

```js
const test = {
  input1: {i: "ytuy"},
  input2: {x: "tyutyu"}
 }

const mapped = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(test).map(
    ([key, value]) => [key, [value]]
  )
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(mapped));
```

That will print out

```json
{"input1":[{"i":"ytuy"}],"input2":[{"x":"tyutyu"}]}
```

The particular error that you got sounds like perhaps `this.state.values` is sometimes `null` or `undefined` and it not always an `object`.  So you'll want to make sure that the object exists before trying to map it.

Answer (score 0):

since mutating the state object is not allowed in react js, here is the fix for my issue.

```
let obj = Object.assign({}, test );  // creates a brand new object
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key=>obj[key]=[obj[key]]);
```